# http.post has no always callback always() in angular 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs

In this angular project I'm getting this error

```
"Object #<Object> has no method 'always'"
```

when I try run this post:

```
var http = $injector.get('$http');


http.post(error_url, data)
            .success(handleAPIResponse)
            .error(handleAPIResponse)
            .always(
            function () {
```

Answer (score 9):

use `finally` instead. this was changed in version 1.2.0